# How to create an immutable array of user input numbers?

Tags: arrays, rust, immutability

I am trying to create an immutable array of user input in rust but the problem is that I have to initialize the array first, and if I initialize the array I cannot insert user inputs in the array.

```
fn main() {
    //error: If I don't initialize the array then it throws and error.
    let arr: [i32;5] = [0;5];
    for i in 0..5 {
        // let i be the user input for now
        // if I do initialize the array I cannot reassign the array elements because of immutability
        arr[i] = i as i32;
    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0594]: cannot assign to `arr[_]`, as `arr` is not declared as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:7:9
  |
3 |     let arr: [i32;5] = [0;5];
  |         --- help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut arr`
...
7 |         arr[i] = i as i32;
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot assign

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0594`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Comment: What if you add `mut` where the error suggests? If you really want `arr` to be immutable you can write `let arr = arr;` later. Is that what you want?

Comment: Let me extend that into an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rust you cannot use a variable without initializing it first. But if at initialization time you do not have the final values, you have to declare it as `mut`:

```
let mut arr: [i32;5] = [0;5];
```

And then you initialize the values of `arr` freely.

If later you want to make the variable `arr` immutable you just write a *rebind*:

```
let arr = arr;
```

As a side note you can always rebind a value to make it mutable again:

```
let mut arr = arr;
```

There are other ways to write that, like a sub-context or a function, but are more or less equivalent:

```
let arr = {
    let mut arr: [i32; 5] = [0; 5];
    //add values to arr
    arr
};
```